# Cakephp 3 using Form Helper and Checkox

Tags: cakephp

I have created a form. Everything worked fine with just input fields. But now I am using checkbox as a type and it just sends a `0` and `1`, either way I check it or not.

```
 echo $this->Form->input('phone', ['type' => 'checkbox', 'label' => ['text' => __('Telefon/Handy'), 'class' => 'moCheckLabel']]);
```

Also for Radio buttons, but there just an empty one and one with `0`

```
echo $this->Form->radio(
                'type',
                [
                    ['value' => '0', 'text' => __('Move'),],
                    ['value' => '1', 'text' => __('Just'),],
                ], ['label' => ['class' =>  'moCheckLabel']]
            );
```

That makes no sence to me, any idea?

**EDIT**: Problem one solved with. Radio Button is still a mistery :/

```
echo $this->Form->input('phone', ['type' => 'checkbox','hiddenField' => '0', 'label' => ['text' => __('Telefon/Handy'), 'class' => 'moCheckLabel']]);
```

Comment: have you tried the [api](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-radio-buttons)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, thanks, I might have overread this.

```
echo $this->Form->radio(
            'type',
            [
                ['value' => '0', 'text' => __('Move'),],
                ['value' => '1', 'text' => __('Just'),],
            ], ['label' => ['class' =>  'moCheckLabel'], 'hiddenField' => false]
        );
```

'hiddenField' => false did the Trick